# jquery event not working on mozilla and work for other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

i have been try to make a responsive design but the click event seems locked on mozilla and work just fine on other browser i have the following  codes

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 $("#serach-button").click(function() {
 var display=$("#head-form").css("display");
 if(display!="none"){
  $("#head-form").fadeOut();
 }else{
  $(".menu").hide();
  $("#head-form").show();
 }
 });
  });
```

```html
<div class="button-responsiv-list">
<button class="button-responsiv"><i id="serach-button"class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
<button class="button-responsiv"><i id="navbar-button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></button>
<button class="button-responsiv" ><i id="sidebar-button-show"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-right"></i>
<i id="sidebar-button-hide" style="display:none;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left"></i>
</button>
</div>
```

i had tried the e.preventDeafualt() but still not working.

Comment: had this happen to me some time ago too. right after e.preventDeafualt(); add return false; or just return false; instead of preventDefault

Comment: i tried this code e.preventDefault();
 return false; but not working

Comment: And where, in your markup, is `#head-form`?

Comment: #head-form is a div hear the exemple [link](http://http://www.demos.amp47ds.com)

Comment: That link is broken. You can update your markup in the question with minimal markup.

Comment: http://www.demos.amp47ds.com this like is work restor down the browser window and click on the right buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try live binding the event and see if that makes a difference. The other issue may be your css as the italic tag is an inline element you may not have a decent target area for the click event (this space can vary from browser to browser). You may want to try binding to the parent button tag instead as this should contain the child element. Also since there is no default action to an italic tag or button there is no reason to include a preventDefault() or return false.

```
$(function(){  
    $(document).on("click", "#serach-button", function() {
      if($("#head-form").is(":visible")){
         $("#head-form").fadeOut();
      }else{
         $(".menu").hide();
         $("#head-form").show();
      }
   });
});
```

Also take note of how you are spelling your class names and id's as pointed out by other people in this thread there are several misspellings and several answers have tried correcting that spelling for you.

Comment: the problem was on italic i guest you're right the space to click is not found on the <i></i>

Comment: @abdelbasset no it's not (only) about space. It's really because FF don't handle event on objects inside a `button` element. I won't call it a bug, since I don't know what the good behavior should be. ([specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) only say that "It is illegal to associate an image map with an IMG that appears as the contents of a BUTTON element.")  *have a look at my answer for an example.*

Answer (score 1):

Actually I will upvote your question because it leads to an *issue* I didn't know before :

elements embedded inside a buttton in FF will lose their click event.

```js
$("#p").click(function() {
  alert('hello');
});

document.getElementById('i').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert('hello2');
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b">
  <img id="i" src="http://lorempixel.com/25/20" />
  <em id="em">elements embedded inside a buttton in FF will lose their click event.</em>
</button>
```

I don't know if it's a bug as [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) only state that

> It is illegal to associate an image map with an [IMG](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG) that appears as the contents of a [BUTTON](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) element.

So for you the solution is to reattach the event to the button (either by giving the `serach-button` id to your real button element, or with `$("#serach-btn").parent().click(function() {`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#serach-button").parent().click(function() {
    alert('hello');
  });
  $("#real-button").click(function() {
    alert('hello');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-responsiv-list">
  <button class="button-responsiv"><i id="serach-button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="button-responsiv" id="real-button"><i id="navbar-button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="button-responsiv"><i id="sidebar-button-show" class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-right"></i>
    <i id="sidebar-button-hide" style="display:none;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button has this class `.search-btn` so, you can try this:

```
$(function(){
   $(".search-btn").click(function() {
      if($("#head-form").is(":visible")){
         $("#head-form").fadeOut();
      }else{
         $(".menu").hide();
         $("#head-form").show();
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: not working the problem is that the event not fired at all i tried alert not working too

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "serach" to "search".

Also you can change jQuery to $:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search-button").click(function () {
        var display = $("#head-form").css("display");
        if (display != "none") {
            $("#head-form").fadeOut();
        } else {
            $(".menu").hide();
            $("#head-form").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the serach is the id name the code work on other browser