# Div not showing up good in Mozilla firefox

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [this plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Pinterest-Style-Grid-Layout-Pinterest-Grid.html) to display books, this result shows good in 
IE and Chrome browser but result does not show good in Mozilla Firefox! What could be the reason ?

- [Good image- Chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVubo.png)
- [Not good image-  Mozilla Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWory.png)

---

[***Live demo ***](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Pinterest-Style-Grid-Layout-Pinterest-Grid/)

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#pinBoot').pinterest_grid({
                no_columns: 6,
                padding_x: 10,
                padding_y: 10,
                margin_bottom: 50,
                single_column_breakpoint: 700
            });
        });

        (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
            var pluginName = 'pinterest_grid',
                    defaults = {
                        padding_x: 10,
                        padding_y: 10,
                        no_columns: 3,
                        margin_bottom: 50,
                        single_column_breakpoint: 700
                    },
            columns,
                    $article,
                    article_width;

            function Plugin(element, options) {
                this.element = element;
                this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                this._defaults = defaults;
                this._name = pluginName;
                this.init();
            }

            Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
                var self = this,
                        resize_finish;

                $(window).resize(function () {
                    clearTimeout(resize_finish);
                    resize_finish = setTimeout(function () {
                        self.make_layout_change(self);
                    }, 11);
                });

                self.make_layout_change(self);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(window).resize();
                }, 500);
            };

            Plugin.prototype.calculate = function (single_column_mode) {
                var self = this,
                        tallest = 0,
                        row = 0,
                        $container = $(this.element),
                        container_width = $container.width();
                $article = $(this.element).children();

                if (single_column_mode === true) {
                    article_width = $container.width() - self.options.padding_x;
                } else {
                    article_width = ($container.width() - self.options.padding_x * self.options.no_columns) / self.options.no_columns;
                }

                $article.each(function () {
                    $(this).css('width', article_width);
                });

                columns = self.options.no_columns;

                $article.each(function (index) {
                    var current_column,
                            left_out = 0,
                            top = 0,
                            $this = $(this),
                            prevAll = $this.prevAll(),
                            tallest = 0;

                    if (single_column_mode === false) {
                        current_column = (index % columns);
                    } else {
                        current_column = 0;
                    }

                    for (var t = 0; t < columns; t++) {
                        $this.removeClass('c' + t);
                    }

                    if (index % columns === 0) {
                        row++;
                    }

                    $this.addClass('c' + current_column);
                    $this.addClass('r' + row);

                    prevAll.each(function (index) {
                        if ($(this).hasClass('c' + current_column)) {
                            top += $(this).outerHeight() + self.options.padding_y;
                        }
                    });

                    if (single_column_mode === true) {
                        left_out = 0;
                    } else {
                        left_out = (index % columns) * (article_width + self.options.padding_x);
                    }

                    $this.css({
                        'left': left_out,
                        'top': top
                    });
                });

                this.tallest($container);
                $(window).resize();
            };

            Plugin.prototype.tallest = function (_container) {
                var column_heights = [],
                        largest = 0;

                for (var z = 0; z < columns; z++) {
                    var temp_height = 0;
                    _container.find('.c' + z).each(function () {
                        temp_height += $(this).outerHeight();
                    });
                    column_heights[z] = temp_height;
                }

                largest = Math.max.apply(Math, column_heights);
                _container.css('height', largest + (this.options.padding_y + this.options.margin_bottom));
            };

            Plugin.prototype.make_layout_change = function (_self) {
                if ($(window).width() < _self.options.single_column_breakpoint) {
                    _self.calculate(true);
                } else {
                    _self.calculate(false);
                }
            };

            $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                        $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                                new Plugin(this, options));
                    }
                });
            }

        })(jQuery, window, document);
    </script>
```

html/php code

```
<div class="row"> 
    <section id="pinBoot"> 
        <?php
        if (empty($query4)) {
            echo '<p style="color:red;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No Books To Display!</p>';
        } else {
            foreach ($query4 as $row) {
                ?>
                <article class="white-panel">
                <?php echo "<img src='" . base_url() . "uploads/books/$row->img1' alt='.$row->book_title.'  title='$row->book_title By $row->auth_firstname $row->auth_lastname' />"; ?>
                <h4>
                <a class="title" href="#">
                <?php echo "$row->book_title"; ?>
                </a>
                </h4> 
                <left> <img src="http://www.homequalitymark.com/filelibrary/interactive_scorecard/4_star.png" style="width:50%;height:12px;"/></left>
                <p> By 
                <a class="link" href="" title="<?php echo $row->book_title ?>">
                <?php
                $afl = $row->auth_firstname . ' ' . $row->auth_lastname;
                $tafln = strlen($afl);
                if ($tafln >= 15) {
                    $afln = strip_tags($afl);
                    $safln = substr($afln, 0, 11);
                    echo "<span class='author'>$safln ...</span>";
                } else {
                    echo "<span title='$row->auth_firstname $row->auth_lastname' class='author'> $row->auth_firstname $row->auth_lastname</span>";
                }
                ?> 
                </a> <br/>
                Number of Pages:<?php echo $row->pages; ?>
                </p>   
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs rent-btn" data-id="<?php echo $row->book_id; ?>"   role="button">Rent</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs rent-btn" role="button">Add to Wishlist</a>
                </p>
                </article> 
                <?php


            }
        }
        ?>  
    </section> 
    <hr> 
    <div id="divId">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968694/jquery-event-not-working-on-mozilla-and-work-for-other-browser

Comment: Works fine for me on firefox? http://i.imgur.com/ONYddcq.png

Comment: The live demo looks fine in firefox. Can you give us a working demo of your implementation or at least the rendered HTML, and not just post your PHP? We don't have access to the data in your PHP so who knows how it's rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I added the description.

The CSS "row" and "pinBoot" selector rules used in the example are not given.

```
<div class="row"> 
    <section id="pinBoot">
```

I've used and tried the original CSS selectors. The problem may be with the "row" and "pinBoot" selectors.

```
<div class="container marketing">
  <section id="blog-landing">
```

It will also work when you add "container" to the "row" class.

```
<div class = "container"> or <div class = "row container">
```

Sorry English is not good, I can't explain more. I hope I can tell.

Please test, example. Code create php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery Pinterest Grid Plugin Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
body {
  background: #E9E9E9;
}
#blog-landing {
  margin-top: 81px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.white-panel {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
.white-panel h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
}
.white-panel h1 a {
  color: #A92733;
}
.white-panel:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  margin-top: -5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
<body>


<?php
$query4 = array(
    array(
        'img1' => 'http://www.mediademon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/food-drink-expo.png',
        'book_title' => 'Is your website converting visits into sales?',
        'auth_firstname' => 'Roberto',
        'auth_lastname' => 'Doleto',
        'pages' => '23',
        'book_id' => '2'
    ),
    array(
        'img1' => 'http://www.mediademon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/food-drink-expo.png',
        'book_title' => 'Is your website converting visits into sales?',
        'auth_firstname' => 'Roberto',
        'auth_lastname' => 'Doleto',
        'pages' => '23',
        'book_id' => '2'
    ),
    array(
        'img1' => 'http://www.mediademon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/food-drink-expo.png',
        'book_title' => 'Is your website converting visits into sales?',
        'auth_firstname' => 'Roberto',
        'auth_lastname' => 'Doleto',
        'pages' => '23',
        'book_id' => '2'
    ),
    array(
        'img1' => 'http://www.mediademon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/food-drink-expo.png',
        'book_title' => 'Is your website converting visits into sales?',
        'auth_firstname' => 'Roberto',
        'auth_lastname' => 'Doleto',
        'pages' => '23',
        'book_id' => '2'
    ),
    array(
        'img1' => 'http://www.mediademon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/food-drink-expo.png',
        'book_title' => 'Is your website converting visits into sales?',
        'auth_firstname' => 'Roberto',
        'auth_lastname' => 'Doleto',
        'pages' => '23',
        'book_id' => '2'
    ),
    array(
        'img1' => 'http://www.mediademon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/food-drink-expo.png',
        'book_title' => 'Is your website converting visits into sales?',
        'auth_firstname' => 'Roberto',
        'auth_lastname' => 'Doleto',
        'pages' => '23',
        'book_id' => '2'
    ),
    array(
        'img1' => 'http://www.mediademon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/food-drink-expo.png',
        'book_title' => 'Is your website converting visits into sales?',
        'auth_firstname' => 'Roberto',
        'auth_lastname' => 'Doleto',
        'pages' => '23',
        'book_id' => '2'
    ),
    array(
        'img1' => 'http://www.mediademon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/food-drink-expo.png',
        'book_title' => 'Is your website converting visits into sales?',
        'auth_firstname' => 'Roberto',
        'auth_lastname' => 'Doleto',
        'pages' => '23',
        'book_id' => '2'
    )
);

$query4 = json_decode(json_encode($query4));

?>


<h1 style="margin-top:150px" align="center">jQuery Pinterest Grid Plugin Example</h1>
<div class="container marketing">
<section id="blog-landing">

<?php foreach ($query4 as $row) { ?>

<article class="white-panel">

<?php echo "<img src='{$row->img1}' alt='.{$row->book_title}.'  title='{$row->book_title} By {$row->auth_firstname} {$row->auth_lastname}' />"; ?>
<h4><a href="#"><?php echo "$row->book_title"; ?></a></h4>
<p>

<a class="link" href="" title="<?php echo $row->book_title ?>">
<?php
$afl = $row->auth_firstname . ' ' . $row->auth_lastname;
$tafln = strlen($afl);
if ($tafln >= 15) {
    $afln = strip_tags($afl);
    $safln = substr($afln, 0, 11);
    echo "<span class='author'>$safln ...</span>";
} else {
    echo "<span title='{$row->auth_firstname} {$row->auth_lastname}' class='author'> {$row->auth_firstname} {$row->auth_lastname}</span>";
}
?> 
</a> <br/>
Number of Pages:<?php echo $row->pages; ?>

</p>
<p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs rent-btn" data-id="<?php echo $row->book_id; ?>"   role="button">Rent</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs rent-btn" role="button">Add to Wishlist</a>
</p>
</article>

<?php } ?>

</section>
</div>



<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== --> 
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster --> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Pinterest-Style-Grid-Layout-Pinterest-Grid/pinterest_grid.js"></script> 
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#blog-landing').pinterest_grid({
                no_columns: 4,
                padding_x: 10,
                padding_y: 10,
                margin_bottom: 50,
                single_column_breakpoint: 700
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add a description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some `console.log()`'s to all the JS handlers to ensure they are firing as expected in all browsers.

As your code is dependant on your data set it is difficult to test. Have you considered using just bootstrap. this will result in a more grid like layout.  note bootstrap col class on the article

```
<?php
    if (empty($query4)) {
        echo '<p style="color:red;">No Books To Display!</p>';
    } else {
            var counter =0;
            foreach ($query4 as $row) {
                if (counter % 6 == 0) {
                    echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
                }
                counter ++;
                ?>
                <article class="white-panel col-xs-2"><!-- note bootstrap col class 2 -->
                    <?php echo "<img src='" . base_url() . "uploads/books/$row->img1' alt='.$row->book_title.'  title='$row->book_title By $row->auth_firstname $row->auth_lastname' />"; ?>
                    <h4>
                        <a class="title" href="#">
                            <?php echo "$row->book_title"; ?>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                    <left> <img src="http://www.homequalitymark.com/filelibrary/interactive_scorecard/4_star.png" style="width:50%;height:12px;"/></left>
                    <p> By
                        <a class="link" href="" title="<?php echo $row->book_title ?>">
                            <?php
                            $afl = $row->auth_firstname . ' ' . $row->auth_lastname;
                            $tafln = strlen($afl);
                            if ($tafln >= 15) {
                                $afln = strip_tags($afl);
                                $safln = substr($afln, 0, 11);
                                echo "<span class='author'>$safln ...</span>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<span title='$row->auth_firstname $row->auth_lastname' class='author'> $row->auth_firstname $row->auth_lastname</span>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </a>
                        <br/>
                        Number of Pages:<?php echo $row->pages; ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs rent-btn" data-id="<?php echo $row->book_id; ?>"   role="button">Rent</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs rent-btn" role="button">Add to Wishlist</a>
                </p>
            </article>
            <?php


        }
    }
?>
```

also consider using external css instead of `<br/>`, inline css and `&nbsp;`'s